# Show links only to sub menus items, not to parent menu

Tags: routes, theming, navigation

I added some links to Main menu and created sub links for it. Now the problem is that I've to give url to the parent menus of sub links. I want it to be disabled. Links should be for sub menus only. How can I do it. Please help. In the pic, I don't want link for 'Contact us

> [image: In the pic, I don't want link for 'Contact us']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Menu item container](https://drupal.org/project/menu_item_container) module, containers have no URL path associated with them. So they are not links, just regular text

> By default, the Drupal menu system only allows you to add menu items
>   that are links. With this module, you can add menu items that are
>   simply containers, and not links.

[image]

also look into [Special menu items](https://drupal.org/project/special_menu_items) and [Menu Firstchild](https://drupal.org/project/menu_firstchild) modules.